# CSS 3D transform strange behavior

Tags: html, css, 3d

I'm trying to show animated cuboids, but I'm stuck with a rendering issue. The side panels of my cubes are glitching through the front panel in Firefox and Chrome too.

Here is a codepen to my original issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaPaeg

I have narrowed down the problem in Chrome when the cube in the original state(not rotated anywhere) and only the front and the left side panels are added. The following code will produce the issue on Chrome:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPGooe

You might need to resize the width of the panel to see the result as perspective+actual with might suppress the issue.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.c {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.front {
  background: #f00;
}
.side {
  background: #0a0;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translate3d(-100px, 0px, 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c">
    <div class="p front"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <div class="p side"></div>
    <div class="p front"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <div class="p side"></div>
    <div class="p front"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <div class="p side"></div>
    <div class="p front"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <div class="p side"></div>
    <div class="p front"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the question is, what is the solution for this issue?